# Connect to AWS ElastiCache with In-Transit Encryption from AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-elasticache

I am using AWS EKS, and i need to connect ElastiCache Redis.
How can i connect to ElastiCache with in-transit?
I tried to use Laravel to connect redis. This is my config

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

        'options' => [
            'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tls'),
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],
```

And result

```
2021-11-18 11:20:21] production.ERROR: Operation timed out {"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): Operation timed out at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:141)
```

Any helps?